# Show one table that is linked by value to another

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and some points are difficult for me to understand.
I have 2 tables:

**Departments**

```
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
head_of_department INT NOT NULL
```

**Lectors**

```
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
first_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
last_name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
degree VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
salary INT NOT NULL
```

Departments.head_of_department refers to Lectors.id

I need to display lector who is head of department in Department with name X.

If it's possible to select ALL table Lectors and ONLY table Lectors without listing all of its columns. For example, a table may have 100 columns and it would be inconvenient to write the names of all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Lectors.*
FROM Departments
INNER JOIN Lectors ON (Departments.head_of_department = Lectors.id)
WHERE Departments.name = 'Department Name You Want';
```

Comment: I was a bit more verbose in here than necessary. Hopefully seeing it like this will make it a bit easier to understand. Let me know if you want any clarification or if I misunderstood your request.

Comment: Great answer, everything works! But I'm wondering if it's possible to select ALL table Lectors and ONLY table Lectors without listing all of its columns. For example, a table may have 100 columns and it would be inconvenient to write the names of all of them

Comment: `SELECT Lectors.*` will select all the columns from the Lectors table. Just be careful that you don't also select another column from a different table which has the same name unless you give it a specific alias to distinguish it. I edited my answer to reflect this.